# Помогите распарсить XML в T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеем:

```
declare @x as  xml
select @x=cast('<Response>
  <Count>1</Count>
  <message>
    <state code="ACCEPT" date="05.07.2016 11:02:38">The message has been successfully processed and added to the queue for delivery.</state>
    <reference>04E1456482</reference>
  </message>
  <Requests>0 &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;message&gt;&lt;oa&gt;ALIAS&lt;/oa&gt;&lt;da&gt;380678451258&lt;/da&gt;&lt;charset&gt;ucs2&lt;/charset&gt;&lt;text&gt;Test text text text&lt;/text&gt;&lt;valid-till&gt;20160712235959&lt;/valid-till&gt;&lt;/message&gt;
</Requests>
</Response>' as xml)
```

Пробую получить значение тега "Requests". Пробовал разными вариантами, но не вышло. Например, так:

```
select c.value('@Requests', 'nvarchar(max)')
from @x.nodes('GmsResponse') t(c)
```

Вроде бы все логично, но NULL возвращает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем я не прав.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы указали символ `@` который используется для доступа к атрибутам, а вам нужен просто тэг.

```
select @x.value('(/Response/Requests)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

Comment: Спасибо! А если в теге "Requests"есть друга XML,  как получить значение любого ее тега?

Comment: @Leonard Bertone Ну так достаньте эту XML в переменную типа XML и так же через XPath выбирайте что нужно.

Comment: а как это сделать одним запросом, если я планирую приджоинить таблицу и в case'ах вытянуть тот реквизит??

Comment: Насколько я знаю, одним запросом -- никак. Здесь нужно парсить XML дважды. Тот кто поместил escaped XML внутрь тэга -- сам стрелял себе в ногу.